# PMOS circuit, issues with Vgs

Tags: mosfet, switches, pmos

I'm currently trying to make a simple circuit to shutdown an IC (GPS SIM28ML). So I ended up with this:
[image: pmos circuit]
In green are the voltages measured when activating the NPN transistor, in blue the voltages measured when the NPN transistor is off.

Reading the datasheet of the PMOS, it says that the Vgs is from -0.3V to -1V.
Then there is thi graph:
[image: Vgs graph]

I dont understand what am I doing wrong, I tried searching in other posts before making this one but i still dont understand it.

EDIT: R2 goes to GND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your GPIO is set at 0 volts, Q1 will be on and, if the GPIO is higher in voltage, Q1 will still be on. This means M1 will always be on: -

[image]

You need to connect R2 to ground and not 3.3 volts.

Alternatively, why don't you ditch Q1 and directly drive M1 from the GPIO via a 100 ohm resistor.

What load are you using and what voltage are you measuring across the load? Also double check you have fitted the correct MOSFET and that you have drain and source the correct way round. Double check these things.

> *Thanks for the help you provided me, the problem was the mosfet drain
> and source being the wrong way round. Now the circuit works with the
> 100ohm resitor just fine. I also tried the circuit with the npn
> transistor and it works too. So thank you, not only you helped me
> getting it to work but also to minimize parts list*

Comment: I see that the R2 is actually to ground in the circuit I made, I'll edit the image.

Comment: You say that M1 will always be on, how do I turn it off? can you help? Thank you

Comment: Now you’ve made my answer look wrong. That’s the wrong way to go about asking for help.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, it was not my intention

Comment: I tried driving the pmos via 100ohm resistor as you said, but the result is the same.
Could it be that the mosfet is not the right one for this 3.3v application?

Comment: Is it ok if I delete this post and start all over again? I ended up really confused and I am really new to this

Comment: The datasheet for the Mosfet says that its THRESHOLD voltage is -0.3V to 1V. The threshold voltage is explained to be when the mosfet is almost turned OFF (1mA) not when it is turned ON. The graph is for a "typical" one but maybe yours needs more Vgs than a typical one.

Comment: Thanks for the help you provided me, the problem was the mosfet drain and source being the wrong way round.
Now the circuit works with the 100ohm resitor just fine. I also tried the circuit with the npn transistor and it works too.
So thank you, not only you helped me getting it to work but also to minimize parts list